# Can we create new docker repository in private Docker registery from Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, docker-registry

As I am very new to docker, I am not sure if I have asked right question here. I just know few basics of Docker. We have on premise local private docker registry where we are creating repositories and uploading images there. We want to automate the whole process right from creating new repository to building the image and pushing it into docker registry. As far as I have searched on Google, I see the results of creating repository only from UI. Is there a way to create it from Jenkinsfile or command line?

Comment: "private docker hub" - do you mean "private docker registry"?

Comment: It's depend on which docker repository you are using. Does it support api to create new repo?

Comment: @sergkondr I guess you are right. That's what I meant. I have also edited my question.

Comment: @nhancao I am not sure how this works. I will have to check if it supports api to create new repo as this is local registery.

Comment: Can you find out what solution is using as docker registry? It is important, because different registry works differently

Comment: Are you talking about creating new Git/SCM repository or something else ? If you are talking about creating SCM repository then you should check the APIs provided by your SCM provider like Github, Gitlab or Bitbucket , they might give you APIs to create new repository . Once you have this , you can create a new Jenkins job to create repository by calling this API and passing your credentials.

Comment: @fatcook This is not related to any SCM. It's pure docker I am referring to. Someone having good exposure to docker and docker hub might have answer to my question

Comment: @sergkondr I don't understand your question. What solution are you referring to? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

So as we were using "docker trusted registry" as private docker registry, in this registry it was not possible to create new docker repository via Jenkinsfile. We had to do it manually. It may have been possible if it's API's were exposed, but I haven't tried that option.